# I am getting error while executing my code as mediapipe.python.solutions has no attribute selfie_segmentation

Tags: mediapipe

self.mpSelfieSegmentation = mp.solutions.selfie_segmentation
AttributeError: module 'mediapipe.python.solutions' has no attribute 'selfie_segmentation'

Any one has solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I was initially on mediapipe==0.8.3.

Issue was resolved once I updated to mediapipe==0.8.9.1 using `pip install mediapipe==0.8.9.1`.